# Devise subdomains - from www.appname.com/admin/login to admin.appname.com/login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have two Devise models: users and admins.

Current my routes to admins are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admin', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}
end
```

I want to change from www.appname.com/admin/login to admin.appname.com/login

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect the user when visiting `/admin/login` on the `www` domain, so you should create a route for that:

```
constraints :subdomain => "www" do   
  match "/admin/login" => redirect { |params| "http://admin.appname.com/login" }
end
```